# Select whole columns by a word in the first row

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) given from an excel sheet. In the first row of the date frame it's always "correct" or "wrong", the other rows are filled with data. 
Now I want to select all the Columns where the first row says "correct" by using the function apply.

I tried:

```
apply(df,2,function(df) grepl ("correct",df))
```

The answer is just a data frame with TRUE and FALSE. How can I select the columns without losing the data in the other rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i <- sapply(df, function(x) x[1] =='correct')

df[,i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a loop. The following should work,

```
df[,df[1,] == 'correct']
```